# Does elastic search have a query manager?

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I am using sense when I want to query elasticsearch.
It is pretty complicated to build a query, manage them, and results are hard to display in a table.
(I usually copy to a json to csv tool which often helps a lot ).
Is there a tool/way to easily build and manage queries (with intelisense maybe) over elastic search?

Comment: You can use kibana- It is a visualization tool for ES queries.

Answer (score 2):

For displaying data, you can use *Elasticsearch Browser*.

https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/elasticsearch-browser/wiki

Nested data goes wrong, but it's nice for one-level data.